# Book rec(s) for an ASP.NET/C# developer looking to build in JSP+Tomcat?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, jsp, tomcat

I'm a senior-ish C# developer used to ASP.NET & IIS, but a project's come along for which I'll need to use Java/JSP and Tomcat, both of which are new to me.  I've got a bit of experience with Java, but none with Tomcat or JSP, so I'm looking for a book ( or books) that'll help me get up and running with JSP and Tomcat quickly.  (The project is pretty small, incidentally -- just a five/ten-page CRUD app.)

Two I'm considering at the moment:

- [Beginning JSP, JSF and Tomcat Web
  Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599047) (Apress)
- [Head First Servlets and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005407)
  (O'Reilly)

Anyone made this particular transition before?  If so, what book(s) would you recommend for a crash course in getting up and running quickly?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from an overall "similarity" feel, JSF is closer to ASP.NET component model than raw JSP is.

So, if you come in to JSP "blind" you'll be in for a rude shock in terms of what kind of "raw functionality" you will get from the platform.

Now, if you're comfortable with the raw HTTP request cycle, then any (decent) JSP/Servlet book will likely suit.

I like the Head First books, I think they're pretty good.

However, you can go here:

[Free JSP Book](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/books/addisonwesley/ServletsJSP/index.tss)

That's a reasonably modern book. (You may have to register to get the book.)

The key things to look for, IMHO, regard a JSP book is solid coverage of JSTL and, ideally, decent coverage of JSP 2.0 Tag Files.

A lot of books are still stuck in the 1999 world of JSP, and it's a LOT better than that.

But, JSP is not equivalent to ASP.NET, JSF is more like that.

I have no opinion on JSF, I don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

[Tomcat: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003180/)

[JavaServer Pages, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003173/)